# Qt vector size remains same

Tags: qt, object, vector, qgraphicsscene

I have two classes: `point` and `mainwindow`. 
I declared pointer of point class in mainwindow.h as:

```
point *item;
```

I create an object of point class in mainwindow.cpp:

```
void MainWindow::drawPoint(){
    item = new point;
    scene->addItem(item);
}
```

This function enables painting of point in `qgraphicsscene`.

There is a vector that stores `QPointF` values in point class. The storage class is the type of vector.

```
QVector<storage> point_vector;
```

`set_point()`  is defined in storage class that sets the value of point p1.

```
storage store_point;
store_point.set_point(p1);
point_vector.push_back(store_point);
```

On iterating the vector in mainwindow.cpp,

```
for(it = item->point_vector.begin(); it != item->point_vector.end(); it++)
{
    qDebug() << "size" << item->point_vector.size() << "\n";
}
```

Even though I create multiple points in the scene, the size of vector always remains 1.

I think this might be happening because every time the function `drawPoint()` is called, the previous object of point class is over-ridden.

I am unable to figure out how to resolve this issue. Any help will be appreciated.

**Relevant Code**

http://www.paste.org/74408

Comment: Who, when and how the vector `point_vector` changed?

Comment: You should put a short complete example in the question itself.  External links go bad, or they are to obnoxious pages that don't load if you're using adblock.

Comment: -1 Since your code a) isn't in a single file (minimal example it isn't) and b) is off-site.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is spread out too much, you should try creating proper classes...

As far as I can see, the "point_vector" that gets pushed back items is a local variable declared / defined in  point.cpp

You did not post point.h file, but I am guessing that it has point_vector defined as part of the class point... But you are not using the point_vector member variable in the cpp, you are using the locally declared one

It would be easier to see if, like the comments on your question say, you posted a more complete portion of the code.